# Acceleration and Velocity Zero at Same Time

Tags: calculus

Since velocity is the antiderivative of acceleration ∫a(t)dt, how would one take a starting velocity and acceleration and determine what constant change in acceleration would be needed for a and v to be zero at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of acceleration is called jerk, so let $J$ be the constant jerk. Then $a(t)=J\:t+a_0$. Plug that in to the integral above and get $v(t)$.

Then write $a(t_f)=0$ and $v(t_f)=0$ and solve for $J$ and $a_0$